# Can I specify ON DELETE behavior in PostgreSQL on a per query basis?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have an `Albums` table and a `Tracks` table. Tracks have an `album` column which is a foreign key to the `Album` table, but that field is nullable. Still, when I try to delete an album, I get an integrity error:

```
Key (id)=(123) is still referenced from table "Track".
```

I would like to force `ON DELETE SET NULL` behavior just this one time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set-up your foreign-key constraint to raise an error instead of doing a cascade-delete or set-to-null. You have two options:

1. Do an `ALTER TABLE` before and after your `DELETE` query to change the constraint. Ensure your `DELETE` is wrapped in an error-handling structure (using whatever PostgreSQL's equivalent of `finally` is) to ensure the constraint is reset to its original behaviour even if your code raises an error.
2. Change your query to an `UPDATE`-then-`DELETE`. This is probably the most sensible approach than changing your constraints:

   ```
   UPDATE Tracks SET AlbumId = NULL WHERE AlbumId = 123

   DELETE FROM Albums WHERE AlbumId = 123
   ```

Comment: The first solution seems to be the best for me because I am actually deleting hundreds of albums. How exactly would this `ALTER TABLE` look like though?